# Append woocommerce category to product title globally?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to append the product category to the product title in woocommerce, this needs to be on a global level (so it works everywhere).

Ive tried the following code which I thought would work but it doesn't, it appends the category name above the product image on archives only

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_add_product_cat', 1);
function my_add_product_cat()
{
    global $product;
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
    $count = count($product_cats);
    foreach($product_cats as $key => $cat)
    {
        echo $cat->name;
        if($key < ($count-1))
        {
            echo ', ';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce uses a single hook to display many things and just changing the hook priorities change the order of elements.

Just change the hook and their order to achieve your goal.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_add_product_cat', 6);
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_add_product_cat', 11);
```

I have given `woocommerce_single_product_summary` priority to `6` because single product title displayed at same hook with priority of `5`.

The same thing I did for archive products title.

Comment: Thanks for the help, following your example I managed to achieve exactly what I needed with just a couple of minor tweaks...

[code]
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_add_product_cat', 4);
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_add_product_cat', 4);
[/code]